# Getting error TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pytest

I am trying to write py.test based test cases. my test.py is

```
!flask/bin/python

import pytest
import config


@pytest.fixture
def app(request):

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sanjeev:sanjeev@localhost:5432/app'

config[SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI] 
db.create_all()
def fin():
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
request.addfinalizer(fin)

def test_foo(app):
    pass
```

My config.py file looks like

```
import os
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sanjeev:sanjeev@localhost:5432/app'
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

But I am getting error TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

below is error log trace

```
                  ERROR at setup of test_foo
request = <SubRequest 'app' for <Function 'test_foo'>>

@pytest.fixture
def app(request):


    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sanjeev:sanjeev@localhost:5432/app'
    config[SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI]
    TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

test.py:20: TypeError
```

Comment: Could you share exact stack trace? It probably refers to specific expression and line in code.

Comment: Added log trace. I am trying to write setup and teardown methods using py.test.

Answer (score 4):

The module `config` is imported. Therefore, you cannot access it like a list:

```
>>> import math
>>> math[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Instead, you could use `sys.argv` if you want to run it from the shell too, or pass it in as a function:

**`sys.argv`**:

`myfile.py`:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

**Running:**

```
bash-3.2$ python myfile.py Hello World!
['Hello', 'World!']
bash-3.2$
```

**Passing it in:**

`myfile.py`:

```
def test(variable):
        print variable
```

**Running:**

```
>>> import myfile
>>> myfile[56]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> myfile.test(56)
56
>>>
```

## Edit:

Your updated file **`test.py`:**

```
!flask/bin/python

import pytest
import config


@pytest.fixture
def app(request):

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sanjeev:sanjeev@localhost:5432/app'

config.take(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
db.create_all()
def fin():
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
request.addfinalizer(fin)

def test_foo(app):
    pass
```

**`config.py`:**

```
import os
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

global myvar

def take(variable):
    global myvar
    myvar = variable

print myvar #Just a test to see if it works

Base = declarative_base()

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://sanjeev:sanjeev@localhost:5432/app'
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

## Testing the above:

My dummy file `config.py`:

```
global myvar

def take(variable):
        global myvar
        myvar = variable

def show():
        global myvar
        print myvar
```

My dummy file `test.py`:

```
import config
variable = [6, 7, 8]

config.take(variable)
config.show()
```

**Running:** *This should print `[6, 7, 8]`*

```
bash-3.2$ python test.py
[6, 7, 8]
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: When you pass it in myfile.py, it is again showing error. Isn't it?

Comment: I did that on purpose just to show you that you cannot call `myfile[56]`. I hope that didn't confuse you, but passing it in works :)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. Can you tell me how to pass it using my config.py and test.py files. I want to write setup and teardown function using  py.test.

Comment: I am working on py.test to write my test cases. I am using command flask/bin/py.test test.py to run my test. Your solution might work for python but I am getting same error for py.test.