# Saving changes to cloned repo on google colab

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I have cloned a github repo which has folders and python files in it. I initially cloned it in C drive, when I run the program, it gives the following error:

```
import click
ImportError: No module named click
```

Someone recommended to do pip install click and it didn't work. So, I cloned it using google colab and performed !pip install click and the program eliminated that error. But now I am having another problem. I can access the contents using !cat filename.py and modify it and then run it on google colab. However, how do I save the changes to the file?

PS: I am using Python 2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to save pip modules into Git repositories. Plus, if it works after installing an external module, there's nothing for you to edit (and `cat` isn't used to edit files anyway, try `!vi`)

You should edit a README file describing the runtime requirements for the project as well as provide a common requirements file like so

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In your documentation, mention

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I used !vi earlier but I got the following error:
`/bin/sh: 1: vi: not found` that's why I used !cat. It would be much easier if I can edit it locally on my computer rather than google colab. I will be able to change the code, save and run it. However, as mentioned that its giving me the error locally but not on google colab. The README file is not there. But, I will keep it updating.

Comment: Try vim or nano, then. Otherwise, there might not be a built in text editor. You can clone a git repo locally. `pip install click`  should work fine if you have pip installed

Comment: The problem that I have now is when I do `pip install click`, it shows that `Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\amy\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (6.7)`. On writing `python`, it shows 2.7.13, however, IDLE is 2.7.12. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I typically use Jupyter or Pycharm for development, not IDLE. I believe Anaconda includes Spyder IDE as well

Comment: I initially used Jupyter. But, the problem that I was having `'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for app = config[os.getenv('CYBERBULLYING_CONFIG') or 'default']`. When, I searched it, I found I am importing a list and I can't use it like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400092/getting-error-typeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-getitem That is why I thought to use locally python. But, seems like I am stuck.

Comment: You did `import config`, which defined a module, not a dictionary. The square brackets say you can't load a value from a module. You need to import a dictionary variable from within the `config.py` file

Answer (score 0):

use `%%writefile` to save the contents to file back within colab instance.

```
! cat path_to_file/file.py
```

copy the content into new cell as following

```
%%writefile path_to_file/file.py
print("update changes to be done in this cell.")
```